# Google Drive V2 update to V3 insert function replace with create

Tags: google-drive-api

As we know that google upgrade the google drive API from V2 to V3 and the insert function is now replaced with the create function.

Please [click here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/insert#php) for more clarification.

For google drive v3 reference please [click here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)

Now my question is as google is provide and example for the insert if you have any example of who create can work and replace this functionality of insert can anyone guide it would be great

I used the same code of insert and just replace the insert with create but its not working can anyone suggest what should I change to use the create

Thanks

Comment: There are some major differences between these two apis.  You cant just replace an insert with a create.   Please edit your question include the code you are having an issue with and describe the issues.

Comment: It really depends what you're trying to do. The documentation for v3 create is [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create). Without showing your code it is impossible to tell what the issue is. What do you mean by 'its not working'? Are you getting errors? Please update with as much information as you can.